# Managing React states correctly giving strange error

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a hangman game using React.

[image]

Here is the code: https://pastebin.com/U1wUJ28G

When I click on a letter I get error:

[image]

Here's AvailableLetter.js:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import classes from './AvailableLetter.module.css';

const AvailableLetter = (props) => {
    const [show,setShow]=useState(true);
    // const [clicked, setClicked]=useState(false);
    // const [outcome,setOutcome]=useState(false);

    // if (show)
    // {
    //     setClicked(true);
    // }

    const play = (alphabet) => {
        const solution = props.solution.split('');
        if (solution.indexOf(alphabet)<0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (!show)
    {
        if (play(props.alphabet))
        {
            props.correct(); 
            // alert('correct');
        }
        else
        {
            props.incorrect(); // THIS CAUSES ERROR!!!!
            // alert('wrong');
        }
    }

    return (
        show ? <span show={show} onClick={()=>{setShow(false)}} className={classes.AvailableLetter}>{props.alphabet}</span> : null
    );
}

export default AvailableLetter;
```

I suspect the error is caused by not managing state properly inside AvailableLetter.js. But I don't know why the error is showing pointing to Hangman.js.

Here's what's pointed to by props.incorrect:
Game.js:

```
guessedIncorrectHandler = (letter) => {
        const index = this.state.availableLetters.indexOf(letter);
        let newAvailableLetters = [...this.state.availableLetters];
        newAvailableLetters.splice(index,1);

        let newUsedLetters = [...this.state.usedLetters];
        newUsedLetters.push(letter);

        const oldValueLives = this.state.lives;
        const newValueLives = oldValueLives - 1;

        this.setState({
            usedLetters: newUsedLetters,
            availableLetters: newAvailableLetters,
            lives: newValueLives
        });
    };
```

Applied fix kind user suggested on

```
lives: newValueLives < 0 ? 0 : newValueLives
```

But now when I lick on a letter I get multiple letters get added randomly to correct letters and incorrect letters on a single click.

If I interrupt guessedIncorrectHandler with return true:

```
guessedIncorrectHandler = (letter) => {
        const index = this.state.availableLetters.indexOf(letter);
        let newAvailableLetters = [...this.state.availableLetters];
        newAvailableLetters.splice(index,1);

        let newUsedLetters = [...this.state.usedLetters];
        newUsedLetters.push(letter);

        const oldValueLives = this.state.lives;
        const newValueLives = oldValueLives - 1;

        console.log('[newValueLives] ',newValueLives); return true; // HERE INTERRUPTED

        this.setState({
            usedLetters: newUsedLetters,
            availableLetters: newAvailableLetters,
            lives: newValueLives < 0 ? 0 : newValueLives
        });
    };
```

Now when I click 'a' for example (which is correct since solution is 'apple') it behaves correctly.

When app is running I get warning:

```
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
in AvailableLetter (at Letters.js:8)
...
```

Probably the cause for this warning is inside AvailableLetter.js inside return:

```
show ? <span show={show} onClick={()=>{setShow(false)}} className={classes.AvailableLetter}>{props.alphabet}</span> : null
```

Tried to set up codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-breeze-o633v

Comment: If you console.log `newValueLives` before setting to the state, what does it show?

Comment: If I click on a wrong letter lives gets decreased form 9 to 8.

Comment: ok, so then it probably becomes a negative number at some point and that's not a valid length value for Array constructor.

Comment: strangely clicking on a correct letter also decreases lives to 8.

Comment: If you could make a runnable sandbox, that would be easier to debug.

Comment: in codesandbox above need to fix index.js ReactDOM.render()

Answer (score 0):

The issue can occur if the `lives` value is a negative number.

Try to secure that possibility:

```
this.setState({
   usedLetters: newUsedLetters,
   availableLetters: newAvailableLetters,
   lives: newValueLives < 0 ? 0 : nevValueLives, // if lives is negative, assign 0
});
```

Comment: now correct letters and incorrect letters are random garbage when i click on a letter. one click gets multiple letters get added.

Comment: @logan However the issue related with "Incorrect Array length" does not occur anymore, right?

Comment: that's correct but the game logic is broken. i think it's to do with not managing states properly.

Comment: @logan The current issue that you are facing has to be related with something else, since that particular change that I've posted doesn't really affect the whole logic that much. You should probably debug your game once again or if needed just simply ask a new question

Comment: I don't know where the underlying error is so I don't know what to ask at this stage.

Comment: @logan Yeah, it may be some very little puzzle that is missing in that whole maze. I would suggest you to go through the code once again, use console.logs where you can and slowly debug it. I believe that you will find what's wrong by yourself. If not - feel free to ask for help on Stack Overflow again:)